# How can I write an algorithm in latex or overleaf?

Tags: vertical-alignment, algorithms

How can I write code like this in latex or overleaf?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX Stack Exchange! There are certain packages as `listings` or `minted` that achieve what you want.

Comment: Have a look at https://ctan.org/pkg/listings

Comment: This seems to have been obtained with `algorithm2e`.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`algorithm2e`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\DontPrintSemicolon
\SetKwInput{Input}{Input}
\SetKwInput{Output}{Output}
\SetKw{To}{ to }
\SetKw{Print}{Print }

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{PrintK}
  \Input{Integers $n_1, n_2, \ldots, n_m$ each of which is $\geq 1$}
  \Output{None}
  $k \gets 0$\;
  \For{$i_1 \gets 1 \To n_1$}{%
    \For{$i_2 \gets 2 \To n_2$}{%
      $\cdot$\;
      $\cdot$\;
      $\cdot$\;
      \For{$i_m \gets 1 \To n_m$}{%
        $k \gets k + 1$\;
      }
    }
  }
  \Print $k$
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much